# How can I make div area on Google map

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make a div area on the Google map iframe. Part of my code is ready here (http://thewebcookies.home.pl/test.html). That image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/92gkt.png) is an example what I want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this div below the map iframe

```
<div class="modal">
    <!-- text and input box go here -->
</div>
```

and add the following CSS

```
.modal {
    width: 500px;
    height: 160px;
    background: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 250px;
}
```